# Performance differential between omitting and changing an attribute of an HTML element

Tags: html, dom, attributes

I've got a `div` that's intermittently hidden in my app.

```html
<!-- Hidden -->
<div aria-hidden="true">...</div>
```

When making the `div` visible I omit the `aria-hidden` attribute, keeping the DOM clean and relying on the fact that the `div` is visible by default.

```html
<!-- Visible -->
<div>...</div>
```

Is there any performance differential between the previous approach where I omit the attribute altogether, and the next approach where I change the attribute's value to `false`?

```html
<!-- Visible -->
<div aria-hidden="false">...</div>
```

I'm aware that if there's a difference it'll be small. Presumably still measurable, though. This is an academic question more than anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a test for this here: https://jsperf.app/fapozi

Setting up the test with:

```html
<div id="demo" aria-hidden="true">
    demo element
</div>
```

```js
const el = document.getElementById('demo');
```

Test case 1 is:

```js
el.removeAttribute('aria-hidden');
el.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
```

Test case 2 is:

```js
el.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'false');
el.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
```

Here are the results for Firefox and Chrome on my machine
[image]

[image]

---

### Results

Apparently using `removeAttribute` is slightly faster!

Answer (score 1):

Removing an attribute is faster:

```
Cycles: 1000000 / Chrome/117
---------------------------------------------------------
attribute remove   449/min  1.0x  463  449  463  460  464
attribute change   532/min  1.2x  547  541  532  545  553
---------------------------------------------------------
https://github.com/silentmantra/benchmark
```

```html
<div id="el" aria-hidden="true">...</div>
<script benchmark="1000000">

// @benchmark attribute remove

el.removeAttribute('aria-hidden');
el.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
'';

// @benchmark attribute change
el.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'false');
el.setAttribute('aria-hidden', 'true');
'';

</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```